# R: why did why didn't FUN=max work for me when I used aggregate()?

Tags: r, aggregate

R noob here:
I am trying to combine rows with the same id, but instead of writing the max value to the merged columns (which is what I want) the function I used, aggregate(), returned other values. I don't know why... it doesn't seem like it's just returning the sum either!

EXAMPLE OF part of my data frame before (1308 observations, 22 columns):

```
ID  gen_col loc_col gen_comp    loc_comp
12434   0   1   1   1
12434   0   0   1   1
12434   0   1   0   0
23536   1   1   0   0
23536   1   0   1   0
23536   0   0   0   0
245345  0   0   1   0
245345  1   0   1   1
36476   0   0   1   0
36476   1   1   1   0
```

`merge_ID <- aggregate(.~org_ID, uwcf_relation_long, max)`

It merged my IDs, but returned values of 1 or 2 in every column and row. I don't know why, it doesn't seem like it gave the sum, because some of the repeated three IDs are all 0

I just want it return a 1 if there is at least one value of 1 and a 0 if there are none

like this:

```
ID  gen_col loc_col gen_comp    loc_comp
12434   0   1   1   1
23536   1   1   1   0
245345  1   0   1   1
36476   1   1   1   0
```

After that I plan on finding the

1. sum of the columns (I think I know how to do this)
2. finding out which columns appear together with the highest frequency, lowest frequency, etc. - across the 22 variables(I have no idea what function I need for this, but one thing at a time, right...)

Comment: I would check `str(uwcf_relation_long)` to make sure all your variables aren't, in fact, factors rather than integer or numeric.

Comment: You're right! They were factors! that must have happened when I was switching between long and wide at some point! oops. okay... erm... so how do I change them back to numeric or integers?

Comment: Questipn is not clear. You mention merge a few times but show only one data frame. `aggregate` does not `merge`. Also, sample data does not have `org_ID`?

Comment: Sorry, like I said, R noob. I do not have the vocabulary down. 
I managed to go back and figure out where my variables switched to being factors and fix it! Thanks, Joran!

Comment: This example may be of help `uwcf_relation_long %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(across(everything(),  ~ sum(. > 0)))`. As for question 2, to find the frequency using `count()`

Answer (score 0):

Joran's comment was it ... my variables were not factors.